# Custom Function's CompletionHandler for Dummies

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I searched everywhere on the internet but couldn't really deal with the answers I found. So if someone could help me here, that'd be appreciated.

I wrote a function that looks like this:

```
func setImage(imageName: String, completion: ((String) -> Void)?) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.myImageView, duration: 0.3, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.lockImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageName).png")
        }, completion: { finished in
            //execute the completionBlock that was passed
    })
}
```

I call it like this:

```
setImage("lockCheck", completion: { finished in
    print("done")
})
```

Now, how do I execute whatever was passed as completion?
In the function, in the transition's completion block, I tried something like

```
for x in completion {self.x}
```

but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example execute the completion handler right away in the completionHandler of the animation block like so:

```
func setImage(imageName: String, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.myImageView, duration: 0.3, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.lockImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageName).png")
        }, completion: completion)
}
```

You can also run an completion handler with extra parameters like the following (I hope it is clear like this):

```
func setImage(imageName: String, completion: ((Bool, String) -> Void)?) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.lockImageView, duration: 0.3, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.lockImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageName).png")
            }) { (finished) -> Void in

            // Do some things for example print
            print("Hi, this is the animation completion handler")

            // Notice the ? because the completion handler is an optional
            completion?(finished, "some string")

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it compiles here, what version of Xcode you have?

Comment: Ok my bad. I read somewhere that it has to be `completion: (String)` instead of `(Bool)` and so it complained. So that fixed it but it does not really answer the question.

Comment: So can you try to define it better what it is you want? I can extent the answer for you.

Comment: You want to return more params then the default finished bool param in your completion block?

Comment: So you see, this works for now but I'd like to know how to execute the completionBlock if I do not have an animation with completionBlock where I can insert it.

Comment: Ah great. But this appears not to work for anything inside setImage(), say I wanted to print something with setImage() and then do the completionBlock, that's not possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95725/discussion-between-wesley-and-linus-g).